# What happens when JDBC AutoCommit is False and explicit Transaction boundaries aren't set

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Consider that a Java application is opening JDBC Connections to Postgres, with AutoCommit set to false.

On such JDBC Connections, if we execute SQL SELECT commands, then what happens to transaction boundaries? Are there any Implied Transaction boundaries even though AutoCommit is off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

6ton's right and that answer should be accepted. I just want to elaborate a little.

Your application will leave idle open transactions. This can prevent some cleanup work because PostgreSQL cannot mark the transaction as conclusively committed or rolled back. It doesn't matter much if you don't do any write operations (as no transaction ID is assigned) but should still be avoided.

If you SELECT a function that has side effects, those side effects won't be committed and will be lost when you disconnect.

If you're using `SERIALIZABLE` isolation due to configuration, a DB setting or a user default, you'll see data from the snapshot taken at the first `SELECT`. You'll also have database performance problems due to bloat caused by inability to `VACUUM` away old rows. This doesn't happen in `READ COMMITTED` isolation.

You really should do it properly and either autocommit or use explicit transaction demarcation.

Comment: Just to confirm:  If I have autoCommit as False and I don't have to explicit Transaction demarcation, then a Transaction is automatically started by Postgres when the first SELECT (or UPDATE/INSERT/DATE) is executed?

Comment: @Mecon By PgJDBC actually but yes. And *never committed* so data inserted/updated/deleted is discarded. Unless of course you issue a commit request. Disconnect without commit = rollback.

Comment: When I get an Exception during a long running SELECT, the Connection goes in a bad state..  and subsequent SELECTs on that Connection give error msgs about "all commands until end of transaction will be ignored".

..and I don't have the other Msg captured, but it indicated I need to Rollback the transaction because an exception had occurred.

Comment: @Mecon Yes. That is normal. What's the problem? After an error the transaction is in an invalid state and you must rollback before continuing work. Maybe you should turn autocommit on or use explicit transaction management?

Comment: I can't (and won't) turn auto commit on because a lot of other existing code relies on transaction boundaries.  I have to set Transaciton boundaries, but there is a lot of code that doesn't set them.

Comment: Instead of changing code for these badly written classes, I am thinking I will  let the error occurs. I will mitigate the impact, by making sure that Connection Pool does sanity checks before any Connection is returned to a user. That way, the next Use case will never get a Bad Connection.

Comment: 99.9999% of this code doesn't result in exceptions..  so would there be a downside to  never set explicit Transactions and yet use AutoCommit OFF?

Answer (score 3):

Auto commit will not have any effect since you are only firing selects.

The default transaction isolation level will come into play for select clauses - for postgres it is set to READ_COMMITTED. From the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html):

> Read Committed is the default isolation level in PostgreSQL. When a
>   transaction uses this isolation level, a SELECT query (without a FOR
>   UPDATE/SHARE clause) sees only data committed before the query began;
>   it never sees either uncommitted data or changes committed during
>   query execution by concurrent transactions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think I am running into issues where Not having transaction boundaries and having autocommit false, is leading to bad  Connection instances when Exceptions occur.  So even though I am doing only SELECTs..  some "implied" Transaction related activity by Postgres is causing me to have some unexpected Connection state.

Comment: Is there an exception? Would help if you posted the stack trace